# Error al crear apk android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Al tratar de crear el **apk** *(Build>Build APK)*, se presenta el siguiente error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0,
>   0xffff]: 65536

¿ Alguien tiene alguna idea de como solucionar este error ?

Código Gradle app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sunami.work"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Estás trabajando con librerías de google ?

Comment: Añade el código de tu archivo `gradle`

Comment: Es posible que añadiendo `multiDexEnabled true` en `defaultConfig`, solucione tu problema

Comment: Te invito a que primeramente busques en el sitio ya que actualmente existen preguntas que pueden resolver tus dudas. @SpartanDev http://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=app%3AtransformClassesWithDexForDebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suele pasar que mientras estamos construyendo nuestra aplicación vamos agregando cada vez mas y mas librerías, y por ende nuestra app llega a un tope entonces debes habilitar el `multiDexEnabled` a `true`

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.+'
}
```

[Más información](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html?hl=es-419/Multidex)

Comment: Soy novato en android. Gracias por su colaboración, me sirvio de mucho.

Comment: Todos comenzamos así, de nada.